Getting error when trying to run spark-shell first time in cmd
ReplGlobal.abort: bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 49176
[init] error:
bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 49176
while compiling: 
during phase: globalPhase=, enteringPhase=
library version: version 2.12.15
compiler version: version 2.12.15
reconstructed args: -classpath  -Yrepl-class-based -Yrepl-outdir C:\Users\goelp\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-b388112f-8351-4c43-893c-2797057209d0\repl-76370d41-e140-4df3-b5dc-821f05624186
last tree to typer: EmptyTree
tree position: 
tree tpe: 
symbol: null
call site:  in 
== Source file context for tree position ==
Exception in thread "main" scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 49176
while compiling: 
during phase: globalPhase=, enteringPhase=
library version: version 2.12.15
compiler version: version 2.12.15
reconstructed args: -classpath  -Yrepl-class-based -Yrepl-outdir C:\Users\goelp\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-b388112f-8351-4c43-893c-2797057209d0\repl-76370d41-e140-4df3-b5dc-821f05624186
last tree to typer: EmptyTree
tree position: 
tree tpe: 
symbol: null
call site:  in 
== Source file context for tree position ==
    at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort(Reporting.scala:69)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Reporting.abort$(Reporting.scala:65)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anon$2.scala$tools$nsc$interpreter$ReplGlobal$$super$abort(IMain.scala:239)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ReplGlobal.abort(ReplGlobal.scala:31)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ReplGlobal.abort$(ReplGlobal.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$$anon$2.abort(IMain.scala:239)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.errorBadIndex(ClassfileParser.scala:386)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser$ConstantPool.getExternalName(ClassfileParser.scala:250)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.readParamNames$1(ClassfileParser.scala:841)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttribute$1(ClassfileParser.scala:847)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parseAttributes$7(ClassfileParser.scala:921)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseAttributes(ClassfileParser.scala:921)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseMethod(ClassfileParser.scala:623)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parseClass$4(ClassfileParser.scala:536)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parseClass(ClassfileParser.scala:536)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$2(ClassfileParser.scala:161)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.$anonfun$parse$1(ClassfileParser.scala:147)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.classfile.ClassfileParser.parse(ClassfileParser.scala:130)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$ClassfileLoader.doComplete(SymbolLoaders.scala:343)
    at scala.tools.nsc.symtab.SymbolLoaders$SymbolLoader.complete(SymbolLoaders.scala:250)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.completeInfo(Symbols.scala:1542)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1514)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions.scala$reflect$internal$Definitions$$enterNewMethod(Definitions.scala:49)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1134)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.String_$plus(Definitions.scala:1134)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1438)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.syntheticCoreMethods(Definitions.scala:1420)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode$lzycompute(Definitions.scala:1450)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.symbolsNotPresentInBytecode(Definitions.scala:1450)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Definitions$DefinitionsClass.init(Definitions.scala:1506)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.<init>(Global.scala:1213)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain._initialize(IMain.scala:124)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.initializeSynchronous(IMain.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.$anonfun$process$10(SparkILoop.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.withSuppressedSettings$1(SparkILoop.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.startup$1(SparkILoop.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:958)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:203)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1055)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

I am trying to configure spark in my system but getting the above error
